# How to save objects from fabric.js without anti-aliasing?

Tags: fabricjs

First, I'm not a JS developer, I'm just trying to fix an issue that we inherited from the JS developer who left our team.

I have this example to help:
[view.html](https://gist.github.com/alanwilter/178f5edcf98b18cdc0498dd5b305724e)
[fabric.json](https://gist.github.com/alanwilter/365335311add365f8e4f6c1b09b8dae7)

The problem is that when I save the canvas in PNG, both the square and the other objects are saved with anti-aliasing.

I'm looking for a way to save these objects with sharp colour contrast, no anti-aliasing at all.

[image]